# Retrieving GPS Location MKR1400 (Arduino IoT Cloud)

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm currently having an issue trying to retrieve GPS co-ordinates. I wouldn't be very experienced and I feel like this may be something fairly simple - I couldn't find much documentation on the topic and I have looked here - ArduinoCloudThing/CloudLocation.h at master · arduino-libraries/ArduinoCloudThing · GitHub - unfortunately this hasn't helped me much.

All I want to do is retrieve co-ordinates every x seconds and print them in the serial monitor and also visualize the location on the Arduino IoT Cloud dashboard. I have added the CloudLocation variable and defined 2 strings and doubles for the latitude & longitude.

```
#include "thingProperties.h"
#include "sensors.h"

String Latitude;
String Longitude;

double LatitudeD;
double LongitudeD;
```

Then I used the following to try retrieve the values:

```
// coordinates 
  LatitudeD =Latitude.toDouble();
  LongitudeD = Longitude.toDouble();
  location = {LatitudeD, LongitudeD};
```

I'm just getting zeros in my serial monitor when using this code.

```
Serial.print("   Latitude:         "); Serial.print(LatitudeD, 6); 
Serial.print("  Longitude:         "); Serial.print(LongitudeD, 6);
```

Comment: MKR1400 do not include a GPS module, is there any such shield attached to your board?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I don't have any GPS module interfaced atm as I was actually following this tutorial initially which was able to grab geolocation using GSM:

https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/andreiflorian/unifiedwater-v1-13b168

I have ordered a GPS module and will be using it come tomorrow, but I'm just a bit confused as to how he was able to get the location using GSM! Also the code above isn't reflective of how he has done it as I followed his tutorial initially and  my board also keep disconnecting and reconnecting with my USB port - so I decided to try a different route

Comment: As a GSM device, MKR1400 can get location information from the mobile network and that would be the location of the base station you are connected to, not the actual location of the MKR.

Comment: Check out this example: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/MKRGSM/blob/master/examples/GsmLocation/GsmLocation.ino

Comment: Ah ok that makes ALOT more sense - I will be using a GPS module anyway but you have provided clarity on the situation so thank you very much!